# @context httpServletRequest request for post method in jersey is null

Tags: java, android, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0

I am getting multipart msg from android client. I am using jersey webservice to receive that multipart data. I can able to retrieve multipart data. but I can't able to use `@Context HttpServletRequest` request to get user id. My android client is,

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

Log.e("Picture Upload URL is:", QueryConfig.PROTOCOL+ StaticHelper.HOST + StaticHelper.port+QueryConfig.projectService+QueryConfig.sendProfilePicture);

HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(QueryConfig.PROTOCOL+ StaticHelper.HOST + StaticHelper.port+QueryConfig.projectService+QueryConfig.sendProfilePicture);

ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data,StaticHelper.UserID+".jpg");
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("file", bab);
reqEntity.addPart("fileFilename",new StringBody(StaticHelper.UserID+".jpg"));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

my jersey service is

```
@Path("/mobileUserPictureInsert")
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/*")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String save(@Context HttpServletRequest request, MultiPart multiPart)
        throws ParseException {
    BodyPartEntity bpeTokenId = (BodyPartEntity) multiPart.getBodyParts()
            .get(2).getEntity();
    try {
        tokenId = getString(bpeTokenId.getInputStream());
        String userId = "";
        userId = getSession(tokenId, request);
```

the get session method is

```
protected String getSession(String token, HttpServletRequest req)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String value = (String) context.getAttribute(token);

    LOG.info("Retrive Token Value-->" + value);

    return value;
}
```

Here i am passing the request and token generated to retrieve user id. it works for get method. but for post method i am getting null value. pl help me. how to get request for post method in jersey.

Answer (score 0):

What you are now doing is getting the `context.getAttribute()` from the ServletContext itself not from the HttpServletRequest. So it should be something like this: `String value = (String) req.getAttribute(token)`. Also keep in mind .getAttribute() method returns null if no attribute of the given name exists.